# Can a language be "complete" without explicit type casting?

Tags: java, casting, language-agnostic, theory

Can a programming language be "complete" without the existence of *explicit casting*? In essence, is there *anything* we can't do using a language that lacks explicit type casting?

For example, [the post below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21013288/632951) demonstrates that Java requires explicit type casting to write customized generic-type classes.

Are there any other example use cases where we *absolutely* need explicit casting?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some

To reverse automatic primative widening:

```
byte blammy = (byte)(schmarr & 0xF7);
```

Legacy code:

```
public void oldSchoolMethod(List oldSchoolListOfStrings)
{
    String firstValue = (String)oldSchoolListOfStrings.get(0);
}
```

HTTP Code:

```
public String getSchmarr(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    return (String)session.getAttribute("Schmarr");
}
```

Edit: "type increases" corrected to "primative widening".

Comment: "automatic type increases" is not the real name, but I can't think of the real name.

Comment: @DwB, we don't need casting to do HTTP. We only need casting if we use the badly written function `session.getAttribute`. I say it's *badly written* because the function simply returns `Object` instead of a more exact type. Assuming, we have the function `session.getStringAttribute("x")`, then we don't need explicit type casts at all, right?

Comment: Explicit casting is needed as a means of casting a supertype reference to a subtype reference; I don't think it's needed with primitives, though.  Java may have borrowed C's use of `myInt = (int)myDouble;`, but it would have been a better language if it had instead used `myInt = Integer.Trunc(myDouble);` [or `Round`, or `Floor`, or `ConvertExact`, with the latter operation throwing an exception if given a `double` values whose fractional part was non-zero].

Answer (score 2):

Sure, take the `equals` method for example - it has to get `Object` a parameter. (and read [this great chapter of Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) regarding equals and friends)

Comment: But we can do *everything* without needing the **equals** method isn't it? I never find myself ever needing to use **equals**. Is there something we can't do without it?

Comment: Depends on how you define everything. You cannot use most of collections without it, but you may say it's also a library, in this case, my only answer is. YES, we can absolutely avoid casting by re-writing Java.

Comment: And have you never compared strings? this is a use of equals as well.

Comment: A string is an *array* of characters. Comparing strings is equivalent to comparing the characters within the String. Characters aren't compared using **equals**. In fact, the method **equals** is built on top of these means.

Comment: And in the question, I'm talking about explicit casting. The  open-bracket + class-name + close-bracket syntax. That is not needed when we compare Strings.

Comment: Take a look at the String class implementation: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29 The casting there is explicit. Does it really matter if you do the implementation or someone else?

Comment: No you are missing the point. I'm saying we don't need casts to compare Strings. We don't need to call **equals** to compare Strings. There is nothing I know that can't be done without casting, and hence I was wondering: Is there really *anything* we can't do without casting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8648/discussion-between-binyamin-sharet-and-pacerier)

Comment: It sounds like you're asking whether it's possible for a statically-typed language to be turing-complete without casts. So, the answer to that is yes.

In Java, though, casts are oftentimes appropriate (and oftener not).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there is no way to declare an array of a generic type `T`. For example, it is invalid to declare an array using `new T[10]`:

```
public class List<T> {
    T[] backing_array = new T[10]; // this line is invalid,


    public T Item(int index) {
        return backing_array[index]; // and therefore this line is invalid as well.
    }

    //etc...
```

The best alternative solution we have is this:

```
public class List<T> {
    Object[] backing_array = new Object[10];

    public T Item(int index) {
        return (T) backing_array[index]; // notice that a cast is needed here if we want the return type of this function to be T
    }

    //etc...
```

If explicit type casting did not exist in Java, it would be impossible to build generic array lists, since declare an array of a generic type `T` is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I use casting frequently when dealing with libraries that aren't built with generics in mind, or when I need to down-cast some object to access functionality I know is implemented by a subclass, but not by the class that I'm otherwise using.  It's probably wise to check with an `if (foo instanceof Bar)`
clause before making that cast, though.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Assuming that we do not use libraries which does not take advantage of generics, why do we ever need casting?

Comment: Of course we do, or it wouldn't be in the language.  For example, say I've got some method I called, that throws "Exception" - not the most helpful, but it happens.  I can do something like `catch (Exception e) { if (e instanceof AxisFault) { System.err.println(((AxisFault) e).getFaultString()) } else { // do something different }}`

Comment: As far as I know, is it in the language only because generics wouldn't introduced until very much later. You've got some method that throws "Exception". The only reason this kind of thing happens is **because** the language supports casting. I mean do you get what I'm trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

When we deserialize an object (for example from a string) we are required to cast the object in to the class so that we can use its methods.

Comment: I use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html) a lot for serialization, I usually have to cast the object I receive from the `xstream.fromXML(xml)` method in to the type I require. Is there a better way of doing this than casting?

Comment: Now *better* is really undefined, but just so you know, there are tons of ways to parse xml: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Programming_interfaces